# How to debug JSPs in an AEM custom errorhandler?

Tags: jsp, aem

**setup:**

1. a local instance of author (running on 4502 and debugging port on 8000) and publisher (running on 4503 and debugging port on 8002)
2. used this guide (click [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/au/experience-manager/kb/CQ5HowToSetupRemoteDebuggingWithEclipse.html)) to setup 2 debug configurations for my author and publisher local instances
3. Somebody (a person before me) created a custom version of /libs/sling/servlet/errorhandler and placed it in /apps/sling/servlet/errorhandler

My question is on how to do debug the custom JSP page. I placed a breakpoint in the JSP on IntelliJ and it's not stopping on the breakpoint. I know the debugging works as the custom JSP uses a Java class (consisting of 10 lines only) and if I placed a breakpoint somewhere in the class, it stops at that point.

I am looking at this page (click [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/au/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/customizing-errorhandler-pages.html)) and there are no tips on how to debug the custom code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I came across a blog which has a similar implementation. Hope this helps!

http://experience-aem.blogspot.com/2015/01/aem-cq-6-debugging-aem-jsps-with-intellij-idea.html

Comment: You need IntelliJ idea ultimate to get the JSR45 plugin. Does not works on community edition.